# How do I translate this snippet of code into something a GUI could read

Tags: java, user-interface, binary, hex, decimal

I'm trying to create a equation that will translate a hexadecimal to a binary number.
I know what the code is in the standard editor, I just don't know how to translate it so for a GUI

This is my attempt to create it in a GUI environment.

```
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
// Equation  for Binary Conversion
//--------------------------------------------------------------

public void binaryConversion (double binary){
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
    totalLabel.setText(decimal.format(binary));
```

This is the code that translates a hexadecimal to a binary number

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
```

If I didn't have to make a GUI, I would simply System.out.print these methods.  I'm confused.  So far I created a GUI, it's just non functioning.  I need to make it function.  I have a fairly good idea on how to implement actionlisteners, and buttons listeners.  So I think I'll be okay with that.  It's just translating these equations for a GUI that's confusing me.  Any help would be appreciated.

I also need to convert a hexadecimal to a decimal.

EDIT

My attempt to use NumberFormatException.  Still getting errors though.

(this is probably completely off.

```
public void binaryConversion (double binary){
        NumberFormat b = NumberFormat.getInstance(b, 16);
        Integer.toBinaryString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, does this code compile?

```
public void binaryConversion (double binary){
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
```

It is having both a parameter and a local variable called binary.

**Update**

You can use

```
   try {
     Integer b = Integer.valueOf(hexString,16);
     Integer.toBinaryString(b);
   } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
     ee.printStackTrace();
   }
```